# QTimer. What to do if slot are more parameters than the signal?

Tags: qt, signals, slot, qtimer

I am writing a game. By tick timer should work the this slot.

```
void game_process::animate_cell(MainWindow* m, const std::string& s, double x,double y, size_t i, size_t j, const std::string& step)
{ 
    painter.begin(m);
    std::string ss("C:\\Users\\Vardan\\GAmes_lines\\res\\red_" + step + ".png");
    ss += s;
    const char* p = ss.c_str();    
    QImage image(p);
    RECT temp = cal

    culate_cell_rect(i, j);
    QRectF target(x, y, image.width(), image.height());
    painter.drawImage(target, image);
    painter.end();
    m->update(x + temp.x0, y + temp.y0, 60, 60);
}
, that's it,
```

QTimer * timer = new QTimer (this); 
connect (timer, SIGNAL (timeout ()), this, SLOT (render_cell (MainWindow * m, const std :: string & s, double x, double y, size_t i, size_t j, const std :: string & step))); timer-> start ();

But as you can see the slot more parameters than the signal, and hence signals and slots mechanism does not work. What to do?
Here cod

```
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime> 
#include <phonon/MediaObject>
#include <phonon/MediaSource>
#include <phonon/AudioOutput>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QImage image("C:\\Users\\Vardan\\GAmes_lines\\res\\back_3.png");
    m_width = 1000;
    m_height = 800;
    m_game_width = image.width();
    m_game_height = image.height();
    setFixedSize(m_width, m_height);
    m_click_coords.first = 0;
    m_click_coords.second = 0;
    m_timer_tick = false;
    m_timer_id = 0;        
    setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    m_area_x0_coordinate = (this->width() - image.width())/2;
    m_area_y0_coordinate = (this->height() - image.height())/2;
    m_r = new game_process(m_area_x0_coordinate, m_area_y0_coordinate, image.width()/*+30*/, image.height()/*+30*/, 57);
    m_status = false;     
    Phonon::MediaObject *mediaobject = new Phonon::MediaObject;
    QString filename("C://Users//Vardan//GAmes_lines//music//Casino Ambiance Music.wav");
    mediaobject->setCurrentSource(filename);
    Phonon::AudioOutput *audio = new Phonon::AudioOutput;
    Phonon::createPath(mediaobject,audio);
    mediaobject->play();
    QPixmap pixmap("C:\\Users\\Vardan\\GAmes_lines\\res\\background.png");    
    QPalette palette;    
    palette.setBrush(/*this->backgroundRole()*/QPalette::Background, QBrush(pixmap));
    this->setPalette(palette);

}
MainWindow::MainWindow(std::string& str, QWidget *parent):
    QWidget(parent)
{

}

double MainWindow::get_mouse_click_absolute_x_coordinate() const
{
    return m_area_x0_coordinate;
}

double MainWindow::get_mouse_click_absolute_y_coordinate() const
{
    return m_area_y0_coordinate;
}

void MainWindow::set_mouse_click_absolute_x_coordinate(double x)
{
    m_area_x0_coordinate = x;
}

void MainWindow::set_mouse_click_absolute_y_coordinate(double y)
{
    m_area_y0_coordinate = y;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    if(m_status == false)
    {
        m_r->game_loop(this);
    }
    else
    {   
        game_process::RECT temp = m_r->calculate_cell_rect(m_click_coords.first, m_click_coords.second);
        int x = m_area_x0_coordinate + temp.x0;
        int y = m_area_y0_coordinate + temp.y0;
        std::pair<double, double> p;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        start_timer();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for(int i = 2; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            char buf[sizeof(int)];
            itoa(i, buf, 10);
            std::string s(buf);            
            m_r->erase_frame(this, x, y);
            while(m_timer_tick == false){}
            p = m_r->draw_frame(this, m_click_coords.first, m_click_coords.second, s.c_str());
            m_timer_tick = false;
        }
        end_timer();            
        m_status = false;
    }        
}

bool MainWindow::delay(int ms)
{
    QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(ms);
    while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime )
    return true;
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent* e)
{
    qDebug() << "Local:" << e->pos().x();
    qDebug() << "Local:" << e->pos().y();    
    std::pair<double, double> p = m_r->calculate_index_of_the_coordinates(e->pos().x(), e->pos().y(), m_width, m_height);
    if(m_area_x0_coordinate <= e->pos().x() && m_area_y0_coordinate <= e->pos().y()
            && m_area_x0_coordinate + m_game_width >= e->pos().x() && m_area_y0_coordinate + m_game_height >= e->pos().y() )
    {        
        m_status = true;
        m_click_coords.first = p.first;
        m_click_coords.second = p.second;        
        game_process::RECT coords = m_r->calculate_cell_rect(p.first, p.second);                
        Figure* f = m_r->detect_figure_by_index(p.first, p.second);         
        m_r->delete_cluster(this, f);            
    }
    game_process::RECT r;
    qDebug() << "Local:" << p.first;
    qDebug() << "Local:" << p.second;
}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    m_timer_tick = true;
} 

void MainWindow::start_timer()
{
    m_timer_id = startTimer(1000 / 30);
}

void MainWindow::end_timer()
{
    killTimer(m_timer_id);
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *e)
{
    switch (e->type())
    {
        case QEvent::WindowActivate:
        case QEvent::WindowDeactivate:
          return true;
    }
    return QWidget::event(e);

}

I noticed that the timer does not start from paintEvent, and I need what he started with paintEvent. What to do?
```

I adjusted the code following your advice.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "game_process.h"

#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime> 
#include <phonon/MediaObject>
#include <phonon/MediaSource>
#include <phonon/AudioOutput>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QImage image("C:\\Users\\Vardan\\GAmes_lines\\res\\back_3.png");
    m_width = 1000;
    m_height = 800;
    m_game_width = image.width();
    m_game_height = image.height();
    setFixedSize(m_width, m_height);
    m_click_coords.first = 0;
    m_click_coords.second = 0;
    m_next_cell = 0;
    m_frame_count = 2;
    m_timer_tick = false;
    m_timer_id = 0;
    m_matrix_size = 0;
    m_timer_flag = false;
    setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    m_area_x0_coordinate = (this->width() - image.width())/2;
    m_area_y0_coordinate = (this->height() - image.height())/2;
    m_r = new game_process(m_area_x0_coordinate, m_area_y0_coordinate, image.width()/*+30*/, image.height()/*+30*/, 57);
    m_status = false;     
    Phonon::MediaObject *mediaobject = new Phonon::MediaObject;
    QString filename("C://Users//Vardan//GAmes_lines//music//Casino Ambiance Music.wav");
    mediaobject->setCurrentSource(filename);
    Phonon::AudioOutput *audio = new Phonon::AudioOutput;
    Phonon::createPath(mediaobject,audio);
    mediaobject->play();
    QPixmap pixmap("C:\\Users\\Vardan\\GAmes_lines\\res\\background.png");    
    QPalette palette;    
    palette.setBrush(/*this->backgroundRole()*/QPalette::Background, QBrush(pixmap));
    this->setPalette(palette);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

MainWindow::MainWindow(std::string& str, QWidget *parent):
    QWidget(parent)
{

}

double MainWindow::get_mouse_click_absolute_x_coordinate() const
{
    return m_area_x0_coordinate;
}

double MainWindow::get_mouse_click_absolute_y_coordinate() const
{
    return m_area_y0_coordinate;
}

void MainWindow::set_mouse_click_absolute_x_coordinate(double x)
{
    m_area_x0_coordinate = x;
}

void MainWindow::set_mouse_click_absolute_y_coordinate(double y)
{
    m_area_y0_coordinate = y;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    static int  ind = 0;
    if(m_status == false && m_timer_tick != true)
    {
        m_r->game_loop(this);
    }
    else
    {
        std::pair<double, double> p;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        static int s = m_r->get_close_map_size();
        static std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > v = m_r->get_close_map_indexes();
        if(m_frame_count >= 7)
        {
            m_frame_count = 2;            
            ++m_next_cell;
            if(m_next_cell <= v.size())
            {
                game_process::RECT temp = m_r->calculate_cell_rect(v[m_next_cell].second, v[m_next_cell].first);
                x = m_area_x0_coordinate + temp.x0;
                y = m_area_y0_coordinate + temp.y0;
                m_x = x;
                m_y = y;
            }
        }
        if(m_next_cell == 0)
        {
            game_process::RECT temp = m_r->calculate_cell_rect(v[m_next_cell].second, v[m_next_cell].first);
            x = m_area_x0_coordinate + temp.x0;
            y = m_area_y0_coordinate + temp.y0;
            m_x = x;
            m_y = y;
        }
        if(m_frame_count < 7 && m_next_cell < v.size())
        {
            char buf[sizeof(int)];
            itoa(m_frame_count, buf, 10);
            std::string s(buf);
            m_r->erase_frame(this, x, y);
            p = m_r->draw_frame(this, v[m_next_cell].second, v[m_next_cell].first, s.c_str());
            m_timer_tick = false;            
            c = true;
        }        
        if(c == false && m_next_cell > v.size() - 1)
        {
            end_timer();
            qDebug()<<"m_x = " << m_x;
            qDebug()<<"m_y = " << m_y;
            qDebug()<<"m_frame_count + 1 = " << m_frame_count + 1;
            qDebug()<<"v.size() = " << v.size();
            m_r->repaint_cells(this);
        }
        m_status = false;
    }    
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent* e)
{    
    qDebug() << "Local:" << e->pos().x();
    qDebug() << "Local:" << e->pos().y();    
    std::pair<double, double> p = m_r->calculate_index_of_the_coordinates(e->pos().x(), e->pos().y(), m_width, m_height);
    if(m_area_x0_coordinate <= e->pos().x() && m_area_y0_coordinate <= e->pos().y()
            && m_area_x0_coordinate + m_game_width >= e->pos().x() && m_area_y0_coordinate + m_game_height >= e->pos().y() )
    {
        start_timer();
        m_status = true;
        m_click_coords.first = p.first;
        m_click_coords.second = p.second;        
        game_process::RECT coords = m_r->calculate_cell_rect(p.first, p.second);                
        Figure* f = m_r->detect_figure_by_index(p.first, p.second);                 
        m_r->delete_cluster(this, f);
        //this->update(m_area_x0_coordinate + coords.x0, m_area_y0_coordinate + coords.y0, 57, 57);
    }
    game_process::RECT r;
    qDebug() << "Local:" << p.first;
    qDebug() << "Local:" << p.second;
}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if(event->timerId() == m_timer_id)
    {        
        m_timer_tick = true;
        ++m_frame_count;
        if(m_x >=0 && m_y >=0)
        {
            qDebug()<<"m_x  "<<m_x <<"m_y  "<<m_y<<"time |||||| Passed";
            this->update(m_x, m_y, 60, 60);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QWidget::timerEvent(event);
    }
}

void MainWindow::start_timer()
{
    m_timer_id = startTimer(50);
}

void MainWindow::end_timer()
{    
       killTimer(m_timer_id);     
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *e)
{
    switch (e->type())
    {
        case QEvent::WindowActivate:
        case QEvent::WindowDeactivate:
          return true;
    }
    return QWidget::event(e);

}
```

Here's the code repaint_cells()

```
void game_process::repaint_cells(MainWindow* m)
{
    Figure* f = 0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {        
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            if(m_close_list[j][i] == -1)
            {
                f = create_new_figure(j, i);
                m_figures.push_back(f);
                assert(f != 0);
                draw_figure(m, f, i, j);
                m_close_list[j][i] = 0;                
            }
        }
     }
}
```

[enter link description here](http://yadi.sk/d/MXb1cXq64ZgIG)

For two days I can not understand why only one ball is drawn. Тhe remaining balls are not drawn.

Comment: The question comes down to: which class has access to all the information that render_cell needs? With that information you can create a new slot for that class, that then calls render_cell with all the needed parameters.
You could also, instead of receiving the information as parameters query whatever class has the necessary information from within render_cell and keep your render_cell slot.

Comment: The `timerEvent` is an event, so you need to let the event loop process it. From what I see in your source code, you are busy waiting for the timer to fire. That is not how it works.
The `timerEvent` is doing all the time scheduling for you. All you need to do is to call `update()` in `timerEvent`, which will cause updating the screen.
To see an example of how this works, you can have a look at my game [here](https://github.com/jcxz/Pexeso3D), which uses `timerEvent`
itself. The important file for you is `Pexeso3D / src / game / CPexesoScene.cpp ` at the very bottom.

Comment: Also, in your `delay` function you are missing semicolon, which means that your `while` will process only on iteration (probably not what you want, but this may be just a typo).
However, you should stop using `delay` functions like this, because they heavily load CPU. Instead consider implementing some type of state machine in your `timerEvent` or using `singleShot QTimer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see from your code snippet that you are passing a pointer to `MainWindow` to your `render_cell()` function, which I assume is some kind of widget or class derived from QObject.

In that case you could override the `timerEvent()`, which is defined for each `QObject` class and implement your game loop here. This way the parameters of your `render_cell()` could be  be member variables of `MainWindow`, or your entire `game_process` class could be embedded in `MainWindow`.

Also, I think this approach is a little faster than using signals, which might be important for code that has to render something 30-60 times per second and update a bunch of other things.

For documentation see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#timerEvent

In pseudo code, you could implement your game like this:

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
  private:
    game_process *game;
    int timer_id;

  public:
    MainWindow(void)
      : QWidget(0),
        game(0),
        timer_id(0)
    {
      game = new game_process;
    }

    void startGame(void)
    {
      timer_id = startTimer(1000 / 30);   // 30 fps
    }

    void endGame(void)
    {
      killTimer(timer_id);
    }

  protected:
    virtual void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
    {
       // update AI
       // update network
       // render game
       game->render_cell(/* params */);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two main approaches:

1. Simply define another slot with no parameters that will call `game_process::render_cell()`, then connect to the new slot.
2. If you're using Qt 5, use a lambda. See [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) for examples. It would look something like this: `connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){/*call the function here*/});`

I recommend #2.

Comment: Thanks, I try and accomplish your goal